# How to build in auto-updating for an outlook addin?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm building an outlook addin, and I was wondering if there was any standard way to have the addin update itself when we release new versions (or at least notify the user to visit our website and download/install the newest version)? The naive way I've been thinking about doing is just pinging our server every once in a while to check for updates, and showing a messagebox. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hey this is very easy to achieve if you are using vs 2008 (which i guess you are), because vs 2008 adds click once deployment support to VSTO - check below links, they should help you achieve this:

1) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Outlook_Add-in.aspx - this one is combination of msi + click once so that you do not run into security issues with your addin (if it uses registry and other stuff which click once does not allow)

2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136646.aspx

3) http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?ID=42